# XGBoost for a binary classification where features are of different types

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I have a dataset of "questions in an exam" that contains features such as:

- QuestionLength (float)
- averageTimePerQuestion (float)
- hasMedia (boolean, represented as 0 or 1)
- averageOfHardWords (float, lots of NaNs)
- otherScores (float, some NaNs)
  etc.

I want to predict the column entitled "Difficulty", which classifies each question as "Hard" or "Easy". I tried implementing a classification model using XGBoost but as far as I understood I needed to convert these values as 0 or 1 (Hard vs Easy). I actually followed [this](https://gist.github.com/pb111/cc341409081dffa5e9eaf60d79562a03) example. But it doesn't predict anything because I get a `ValueError: unknown not supported`.

Are there any resources where I can find an example similar to my problem?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Please provide the full error traceback. And try to reduce the data to a minimal example and provide that.